# Как Ускорить Запрос к БД?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть таблица на 30500 записей. В ней находятся города, районы, и всякие населенные пункты. Все в одной таблице.

Я написал автогенратор мыла имени и Самое Долгое, по продолжитльности выполнения, 3 запроса из этой большой таблицы, Которые генерируют Область потом город из области и район из этой области.

Как ускорить обращение к бд? Идея возникла использоать union, но тут дело в том что я не вытягиваю три разных массива.

Как быть?

Потому что я в каждом отдельном методе рандомно выбирал область, город, район, а с использованием union SELECT, выдает большой массив в котором рандомно если и выбиру то получится или может получиться, Район, район, область. А хотелось бы четко Область, Город, Район.

В общем нужна подсказка а то генератор долго обращается к базе. именно по поводу каждого обращения и выборке из базы.

Вот пример похожего метода для города и района. В данном случае выбирается область.

```
public function AutoqualiOblast()
{

    $territory=$this->territor;

    $db = DB::getInstance();
    $query = "SELECT ter_address,reg_id FROM t_koatuu_tree where reg_id  = " . $territory
        . " AND ter_type_id = 0 AND ter_pid <=> NULL";

    $result = $db->query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        die($db->error);
    }
    $obl = [];
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $ter = htmlspecialchars($row['ter_address'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $obl[] = $ter;
    };
    $oblast=$this->escape($this->clean($obl[mt_rand(0, count($obl) - 1)]));

    return $oblast;
}
```

Вот то что я пытаюсь упростить

```
    public function UnionSelect()
{
    $territory=$this->territor;
    $db = DB::getInstance();

    $query = "
SELECT ter_name,ter_type_id,reg_id FROM t_koatuu_tree where reg_id  = 63
         AND ter_type_id = 0 AND ter_pid <=> NULL
union
 SELECT ter_name,ter_type_id,reg_id FROM t_koatuu_tree where reg_id  = 63 AND t_koatuu_tree.ter_type_id =1
union
SELECT ter_name,ter_type_id,reg_id FROM t_koatuu_tree where reg_id  = 63 AND t_koatuu_tree.ter_type_id = 2";

    $result = $db->query($query);
    if (!$result) {
        die($db->error);
    }
    $rayons = [];
    while ($row = $result->fetch_all()) {
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump( $row );
        echo "</pre>";
    };


}
```

Comment: Лучше добавьте индексы на поля, по которым делаются условия. Выборка будет быстрее. Но будет занимать больше места. 30500 записей, это совсем не много

Comment: что там в таблице на 30к записей в принципе может долго выбираться? разве что вы возвращаете весь набор клиенту, но вы же ищите только 1-3 записи? и сколько это долго по вашему

Comment: @ teran  ну на 1000 генерацый 15 минут.

Comment: откройте для себя команду sql `explain` не видя плана выполнения запроса и не зная структуры таблиц со всеми индексами невозможно сказать почему он тормозит. (эти данные надо обязательно приводить в вопросах по оптимизации)

Comment: вдобавок уточните вашу задачу саму,  ибо то что написано ясной картины вообще не дает

Comment: Все норм порешал. Сделал один запрос, с union вытащил с помощью цикла все  поля, разложил на их в масивы и из них уже генерировал случайную строку. Которую и возвращал.

Comment: Вместо union попробуйте union all.

Comment: @igaraev И проиндексировать базу.))